# What's the advantage of panel data regression over multiple individual ones?

Tags: multiple-regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

Given a panel data (a repetitive observations over a bunch of entities) $X_{i,t}$ and $y_{i,t}$, where $X,y$ are independent and dependent variables, I am wondering which one of these two -- panel data regression or multiple individual regressions is better?

A panel data regression is something like 
\begin{equation}
y_{i,t} = {\bf B}\cdot{\bf X}_{i,t} + \alpha_i + \epsilon_{i,t}, \qquad \forall i, t
\end{equation}
where the vector ${\bf B}$ are coefficients for the independent vector ${\bf X}_{i,t}$, $\alpha_i$ takes into account the fixed effect (factors that vary across entities but constant in time), and $\epsilon_{i,t}$ are errors. On the other hand, how about to just do $N$ independent regressions 
\begin{equation}
y_{i,t} = {\bf B}_i\cdot{\bf X}_{i,t} + \alpha_i + \epsilon_{i,t}, \qquad \forall t
\end{equation}
one for each $i \in \{1,2,\cdots,N\}$, if we have $N$ entities.

I don't see what's the advantage of panel data regression just by looking at the above two equations. The panel data version sort of saying that every entity shares the same coefficient ${\bf B}$. Thus, can I say panel data regression assumes the existence of holistic effect? For example, some unobserved variable affects all independent variables across entities, and those hidden variables show their effect through the common coefficient ${\bf B}$?

Just wondering why not simply doing $N$ independent regressions?

---

**update**:

After some more reading, it looks like it is the very "fixed effect" and "time effect" that makes the panel regression useful. For example, suppose there are global effects which changes over time but not over different entities. So, we have 
\begin{equation}
y_{i,t} = {\bf B}\cdot{\bf X}_{i,t} + \gamma_t + \epsilon_{i,t}, \qquad \forall i, t
\end{equation}
where $\gamma_t$ is some unmeasured global effect. To deal with it, one simply demean the above equation to get 
\begin{equation}
(y_{i,t} - \bar{y}_{t}) = {\bf B}\cdot \Big({\bf X}_{i,t} - {\bf \bar{X}}_{t} \Big) + \tilde{\epsilon_{i,t}}, \qquad \forall i, t
\end{equation}
One can then do usual OLS regression to estimate the parameters ${\bf B}$. Likewise, by demeaning the time average, one takes care of the fixed effect.

A regression model is biased if there are relevant variables not included in ${\bf X}$. If we did individual regression one for each entity, each individual regression suffers from the omitted variable bias. However, by using panel regression one takes into account these unobserved effects. Is my understanding correct?

**Question**: 
The above argument makes sense of the panel analysis, however, I got a question about how we do prediction. As $\alpha_i, \gamma_t$ are unobserved, we cannot make prediction directly from these modeling equations. I guess, instead, we should estimate $y_{i,t}$ from the demeaned equation (so that we don't need to know what's $\alpha_i, \gamma_t$). 
However, I played with a panel dataset with Python and the prediction method looks like it estimates $y_{i, t}$ by simply computing ${\bf B}\cdot{\bf X}_{i,t}$? (I have computed manually this and it matches with the prediction method of the package)
I am confused as this clearly forgets about the existence of $\alpha_i$ and $\gamma_t$..